# WPF Datepicker Calendar Style Bug

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I am developing a WPF application and I'm using the standard WPF Datepicker.

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5,0,5,12"
  x:Name="SendungDatePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ProduktionsDatum}"
  ToolTip="{x:Static resx:MetaData.DateTooltip}" />
```

However, when I use it, the upper part of the calendar isn't displayed correctly:

[image]

As you can see, I can't see the month and year.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**

I generated a template for the calendar style:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

How can I update the height of the header of the calendar?

Comment: what is the theme you are using? Try generating a copy of theme of datepicker through Blend apply the height of control inside calender based on your culture display.

Comment: @user1672994 What do you mean with theme? I'm using the standard WPF DatePicker.

Comment: I meant to say Template.

Comment: @user1672994 I'm not using any Template

Comment: Then generate the template for datepicker through Blend and update the height of control inside the calendar. The problem here is the for some culture specific text, datepicker label does not show the text for default height in template. Some time at also vary on the OS too.

Comment: @user1672994 Ok, I now generated the template for the calendar. But I can only change the height of the entire calendar, not the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate a style for CalendarItem then you will find that Height of Header Button is 20 and FontSize is 10.5. So you override the `CalendarItem` style and defined either the height of `PART_HeaderTemplate` or decrease the `FontSize`.

```
<Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}" Width="28"/>
<Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Focusable="False" FontSize="10.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<Button x:Name="PART_NextButton" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource NextButtonTemplate}" Width="28"/>
```

Comment: How can I generate a style for CalendarItem?

Comment: You can generate through Blend. Right click on datepicker and click on generate additional template.

Comment: I tried that and I can only select CalendarStyle and FocusVisualStyle.

Comment: Ok, I found the way. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is very simple, the header of your DatePicker is a Button. Surely you have somewhere put a style for your buttons where you specify a height for them.
Solution: if for your buttons you have set ... Height = 20 you must raise the height, Height = 25 Or try until you see that the header is not cut. That's why my friend cuts himself, because the button is not high enough.
I hope this helps someone who ever has this problem, since it's something that drove me crazy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).